# Richfaces confirmation dialog

Tags: richfaces

guys! I am trying to create confirmation dialog in the following way:

```
<h:form>
  <a4j:commandButton id="declareNewStatusCbt" image="/img/buttons/save.png"
  styleClass="hoverable rich-panel-button"
  onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false">
  </a4j:commandButton>
  <a4j:jsFunction name="doSubmit" action="#{customerService.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

Button on the modal panel block is following (rich:modalPanel has `id="confirmation"`):

```
<h:commandButton image="img/buttons/proceed.png" styleClass="hoverable"       
onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();doSubmit();return false;"/>
```

So, basically I need to get the same effect as with `a4j:commandButton action="#{customerService.action}"` but when I press the "proceed" button on the modal window, I receive `TypeError: this._form is null` in FireFox console, and the page simply reloads. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself - this works pretty fine, the problem was in enclosing `<h:form>`. Obviously `a4j:jsFunction` invokes form submitting which is undesirable, it's a shame not to notice this. So, you can simply remove  `<h:form>` :)